# Are SSDs better than HDDs for long term idle storage?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup, external-hard-drive

I want to back up some files on an external disk. I won't be accessing the files as often, but I want them to be secure and private. It goes without saying that I don't want to upload them on the cloud, I want them offline.

So my question is, are HDDs suitable for long term storage, or are SSDs better in this regard? What are the variables that I need to consider?

Comment: Voted to close as dupe, as the linked answer is about how long you can store data on various formats, including HDD and SSDs.

Comment: Mentioned post has enough information about hard disks (thanks), but it doesn't talk about SSDs at all. I also need to know about SSDs in addition to HDDs, to compare which degrades slower.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I disagree with closing.  The linked post *from 2011* contains no information about SSDs in comparison to HDDs.